# How to close User Control from its View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, dynamic-usercontrols

I created my `UserControl` like this:

```
MyUserCtrl myctrl = new MyUserCtrl() { DataContext = new MyViewModel()};
ControlCollection.Add(myctrl);
```

and i output it using this `ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ControlCollection}"` to the View.

It's clean and nice but the problem is I don't know how can I close those `UserControls` that I opened.

And what if I just remove it to the collection. Thus the View Model will close too?

Comment: "It's clean and nice" - not really.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not assign a collection of UI elements to the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl. Instead, put the UI element in the ItemsControl's `ItemTemplate` and pass a collection of view model instances to the ItemsSource.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyUserCtrl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsCControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsCControl>
```

Add a view model item to the collection property in your "main" view model:

```
var item = new MyViewModel();
MyItems.Add(item);
```

To "close" a control, remove the appropriate item from the collection:

```
MyItems.Remove(item);
```